How to cross-compile LLDB with buildroot
Hi currently Im using the latest version of buildroot 2024, the issue is even when they have support for some components of the LLVM-Project, they don't have the option to compile LLDB, so I worked a little bit to create my own package, and be able to compile it using buildroot:
################################################################################
#
# lldb
#
################################################################################

LLDB_VERSION = $(LLVM_PROJECT_VERSION)
LLDB_SITE = $(LLVM_PROJECT_SITE)
LLDB_SOURCE = lldb-$(LLDB_VERSION).src.tar.xz
LLDB_LICENSE = Apache-2.0 with exceptions or MIT
LLDB_LICENSE_FILES = LICENSE.TXT

LLDB_DEPENDENCIES = llvm clang
LLDB_SUPPORTS_IN_SOURCE_BUILD = NO

LLDB_INSTALL_STAGING = YES
LLDB_INSTALL_TARGET = NO

LLDB_CONF_OPTS = \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux \
    -DLLDB_INCLUDE_TESTS=0 \
    -DLLDB_ENABLE_LIBEDIT=0 \
    -DLLDB_ENABLE_CURSES=0 \
    -DLLDB_ENABLE_LZMA=0 \
    -DLLDB_ENABLE_LIBXML2=0 \
    -DLLDB_ENABLE_PYTHON=0 \
    -DLLDB_ENABLE_LUA=0 \
    -DLLVM_TABLEGEN=$(HOST_DIR)/bin/llvm-tblgen \
    -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=$(HOST_DIR)/lib/cmake/llvm \
    -DNATIVE_LLVM_DIR=b \
    -DNATIVE_Clang_DIR=a \
    -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE=$(GNU_TARGET_NAME) \
    -DLLVM_HOST_TRIPLE=$(GNU_TARGET_NAME) \
    -DLLVM_CONFIG="$(HOST_DIR)/bin/llvm-config" \

$(eval $(cmake-package))

I believe I'm close to be able to compile it so I can use it in my ARM virtual machine created by buildroot:
but now Im having this error:
[  8%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/lldb-instr
/run/media/user/8eee-2bf3cf779d66/source/buildroot/output/host/lib/libclang-cpp.so.15: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [tools/lldb-instr/CMakeFiles/lldb-instr.dir/build.make:99: bin/lldb-instr] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6820: tools/lldb-instr/CMakeFiles/lldb-instr.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2

It seems it is linking the host version of that library instead of the target version that was created previously and compatible with arm.
Note: I cannot use gdbserver because the tool we are using for debugging only supports lldb-server
Note2: It seems the native variables are not working but somehow are needed by the CMakeLists.txt
Thanks for any help.

I believe you need to set CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR. Try adding -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=aarch64

Thanks for your comment, tried, but still it is picking up the host library instead of the target one

Did you try with --fresh? CMake caches things on the first run about the target system so it may just be getting ignored.

lldb-instr is not a tool that is used as part of running lldb, it is a maintainer tool for the lldb build.  It used to be used to correctly inject instrumentation in the SB API's when adding API's.  I don't think it's used at present, the feature it was developed for never panned out.  I think you can just leave this one out.  But the same is true of lldb-tablegen, that's used to build lldb so you need a host side version as part of the build.

I suspect that the problem is in -DLLVM_CONFIG="$(HOST_DIR)/bin/llvm-config". This is the configuration for host LLVM. You should instead point to $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/bin/llvm-config.
